# Get Email before Sign In - GoogleSignIn

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-oauth

I have an Authentication to Firebase by Google with SignIn using a Google SignInButton. When you click the Button it displays all the Google accounts you have added in your phone.

- I'm looking for **obtain the e-mail when you choose an account**.
- I **don't need to SignIn** for the moment (it's commented in the code), just display the e-mail in a Toast or something else.

Image of the account selection:

[image]

My code:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;

    private SignInButton signInButton;
    private Button buttonCheck;

    public static final int SIGN_IN_CODE = 777;

    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener firebaseAuthListener;

    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();



        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this, this)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();

        buttonCheck = (Button) findViewById(R.id.check);

        signInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.entrar);

        signInButton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_WIDE);

        signInButton.setColorScheme(SignInButton.COLOR_DARK);

        signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(googleApiClient);
                startActivityForResult(intent, SIGN_IN_CODE);
            }
        });

        buttonCheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               checkEmail();
            }
        });


        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        firebaseAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {
                    goMainScreen();
                }
            }
        };

        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        firebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(firebaseAuthListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    public void checkEmail(){
        firebaseAuth.fetchSignInMethodsForEmail("mytestemail@gmail.com").addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<SignInMethodQueryResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<SignInMethodQueryResult> task) {
               boolean Existeix = !task.getResult().getSignInMethods().isEmpty();

               if(Existeix){
                   Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "EXIST", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
               else{
                   Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "NO EXIST", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == SIGN_IN_CODE) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(result);
        }
    }

    private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(result.getSignInAccount());
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "NO S'HA POGUT CONNECTAR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(final GoogleSignInAccount signInAccount) {

        //progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        //signInButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(signInAccount.getIdToken(), null);

        Toast.makeText(this, "THIS WILL TOAST THE EMAIL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        /*firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                signInButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "NO S'HA POGUT AUTENTIFICAR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });*/
    }

    private void goMainScreen() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainMenu.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        if (firebaseAuthListener != null) {
            firebaseAuth.removeAuthStateListener(firebaseAuthListener);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**One hour later I found the solution:**

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == SIGN_IN_CODE) {
            final GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();

            email = acct.getEmail();
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, email, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            firebaseAuth.fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(email).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<SignInMethodQueryResult>() {

                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<SignInMethodQueryResult> task) {
                    exist = !task.getResult().getSignInMethods().isEmpty();

                    if(exist){
                       Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "EXIST",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "NO EXIST", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: it was the same as FirebaseAuth but with GoogleSignInAccount , lol , glad you found the problem ! happy coding !

Answer (score 1):

To get the email just do this:

```
FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
```

then retrieve the email like this and show "email" into your toast:

```
String email = user.getEmail();
```

Also you can check if user's email is verified:

```
  boolean emailVerified = user.isEmailVerified();
```

Comment: Thanks to much for the reply but CurrentUser only works after the successfull Sign In.

Comment: Finally I found it! :)

Comment: congrats buddy !